# Usage of "How can we" and "How we can" in the following case

Tags: word-order, questions, inversion, subordinate-clauses

### Correct

This is how we can improve XXX.

### Correct

How can we improve XXX?

### May I know, which is the correct form?

1. Would you mind telling us how we can improve XXX?
2. Would you mind telling us how can we improve XXX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatical, whereas the second one is not so.

The phrase "Would you mind" is in the interrogative. So the how clause should be declarative (normal), not interrogative.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you gave is in the correct form however for clarity the "How" should be removed in the second example. However, I am not sure what your context is and there is a third form.

Can is a modal verb they provide additional information about the function of the main verb that follows it.

**Would you mind telling us how we can improve XXX?** is about the Ability of improving.

**we can** improve.

> can: ability: example I can swim.

To clarify the meaning would then be **Would you mind telling us how we are able to improve XXX?**

**Would you mind telling us (how) can we improve XXX?** is about the permission to improve.

**can we** improve. Note can we in it's short form should be written **can we?**

> can: permission: example Can I use your phone please?
>   [Use of modal verbs](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-modals.php)

To clarify the meaning would then be **Would you mind telling us, can we improve XXX?**

There is a third use for can, possibility:

> can: possibility: Example  Smoking can cause cancer.

**Would you mind telling us how can XXX be improved?**